# Insert statement won't insert and there are no errors

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add users to a database but whenever I try to add a user it says user added but the database shows that there is no new user.
here is the code:

```
<form method="post" name="input" action=""> 
    <label>StaffID:<br/> <input name="staffid" type="number"><br></label>  
    <label>Username:<br/> <input name="username" type="text" min="0"><br></label>  
    <label>Password:<br/> <input name="password" type="text" min="0"><br></label>   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add User"> 
</form>

<?php
    $SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
    $UN = $_POST['username'];
    $PW = $_POST['password']; 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");

    if($SID !=''||$UN !=''||$PW !=''){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES($UN, $PW, $SID)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

        echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>";
    }
?>
```

I dont know what Im doing wrong please help.

Comment: Your values must be quoted. You should think about sql injection. So use placeholders in your query. You should read a mysqli Tutorial! And you should change your db password now (after posting it here)

Comment: Note that your or's || should be and's &&.

Comment: @steven dont worry about the database it has another login layer to get past as it is on award space hosting a website that it itself needs a password. And the sql injection is only a problem once the statement actually works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
$UN = $_POST['username'];
$PW = $_POST['password']; 

$conn = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");

if($SID !='' && $UN !='' && $PW !=''){
  $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'ssd', $UN,  $PW, $SID);
  if(mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)){
    echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>";
  }
}
?>
```

***Changes***

1. Use [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) & [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to
   execute query.
2. Change `if($SID !=''||$UN !=''||$PW !=''){` to
       `if($SID !=''||$UN !=''||$PW !=''){`.

Comment: the $stmt variable isn't defined.

Comment: My Bad. Try once again @ashjim

Comment: I changed $stmt to $sql and no more errors but it still doesn't insert.

Comment: Then, it's your database connection problem. @ashjim

Comment: that's strange because its all hosted with award space.

Comment: Check DB Name, DB User Name, DB Password and all in mysqli_connect @ashjim

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="input" action=""> 
    <label>StaffID:<br/> <input name="staffid" type="number"><br></label>  
    <label>Username:<br/> <input name="username" type="text" min="0"><br></label>  
    <label>Password:<br/> <input name="password" type="text" min="0"><br></label>   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add User"> 
</form>

<?php
    $SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
    $UN = $_POST['username'];
    $PW = $_POST['password'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");

    if($SID !='' && $UN !='' && $PW !=''){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES('$UN', '$PW', $SID)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

        echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>";
    }
?>
```

You try to insert string values as integer in your database. Adding apostrophes will help your MySQL-statement to insert it as a string.

And be patient: if one or more of your textfields are empty and you can not assign the `$_POST`s to a variable. Therefore it runs into an error.
Check your `$_POST`s with `isset()`.

Also i replaced `||` with `&&` in your `IF`-statement. Inserting empty values could be also produce errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Include proper error checking in your code, then you can see the errors**. You can try this modified code ( derived from your above code : remember **exposing your server details will be invitation for hackers**) ...

```
<form method="post" name="input" action=""> 
    <label>StaffID:<br/> <input name="staffid" type="number"><br></label>  
    <label>Username:<br/> <input name="username" type="text" min="0"><br></label>  
    <label>Password:<br/> <input name="password" type="text" min="0"><br></label>   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add User"> 
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
        $UN = $_POST['username'];
        $PW = $_POST['password']; 

        //echo $SID.$UN.$PW;

        if($SID !='' && $UN !='' && $PW !=''){

            $con = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES($UN, $PW, $SID)";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>"; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**The code will work if you run on the server (on a server which have remote SQL access to the server pionted by *fdb14.awardspace.net* domain address.**

But if you are running the code on localhost or another server which have remote SQL access to the server pionted by *fdb14.awardspace.net* domain address, will get this error : *Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\remote-sql-test\index.php on line 18
Failed to connect to MySQL: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.*

this error is not from your code, this error associated with your remote server setup(remeber localhost is also a server concept), you may need to configure proper remote SQL access, for more details about Remote SQL, refer [cPanel documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL).

Comment: if User added successfully! displayed, login to your panel, and check weather the record is inserted or not. if all is good - mark as answer, you must add sql injection prevention before practical usage.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
<?php
    $SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
    $UN = $_POST['username'];
    $PW = $_POST['password']; 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");

    if($SID !=''||$UN !=''||$PW !=''){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES($UN, $PW, $SID)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

        echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>";
    }
?>
```

use this code for insert user record

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $SID = $_POST['staffid']; 
    $UN = $_POST['username'];
    $PW = $_POST['password']; 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("fdb14.awardspace.net", "2219658_ashtonb", "dojustly01", "2219658_ashtonb");

    if($SID !=''||$UN !=''||$PW !=''){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO staffusers(username, password, staffid) VALUES('".$UN."','".$PW."','".$SID."')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo "<br><br><span>not Inserted!</span>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br><br><span>User added successfully!</span>";
            }


    }
}
?>
```